# samba server connection works on one win 7 not not another

Tags: samba

I have a CentOS 6.6 box with a samba server (3.6.23) running on it. It is configured for ADS.

I also have two Windows 7 PCs, of which one is able to connect to the shares, while the other one is not.

I increased the log level of samba, and the Windows 7 machine which is unable to connect gets the following "error":

```
[2015/10/16 12:20:39.666773,  1] smbd/process.c:457(receive_smb_talloc)
  receive_smb_raw_talloc failed for client 10.6.7.103 read error = NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_RESET.
```

This happens 5 times for each connection attempt, and then the connection fails entirely.

Network security options are the same across both Windows 7 machines. Always trying to login with the same account (login passes in samba logs).

I'm at a loss as to why one works, and the other does not.